# Java compiler is using old source code or not overwriting old class file

Tags: java

When I compile the program I get an error/exception/output based on the previous version of code that was compiled. This has never happened before.

I deleted the all class files and recompiled the source code. Now I get the appropriate output. Why does this happen?

```
    202 // System.out.println("recursion!!");
    203 // System.out.flush();

    204 // add primitives to left child
    205 left.objects = new WorldObject[leftPrimitives.size()];
    206 for (int idx = 0; idx < left.objects.length; idx++) {
    207     left.objects[idx] = leftPrimitives.get(idx);
    208 }
```

The snippet of code is part of a utility class.

some/path/src/misc/utility.java :: utility class location whose code is specified above

some/path/src/main.java :: main class of the java program.

to compile

javac main.java

where current directory is src/

The program should NOT print "recursion!!". But the program instead prints recursion!! and exits eventhough it was commented out. The previous version of source code had the print statements uncommented.

I checked out the question posted here:
[Java compiler is using old version of source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979245/java-compiler-is-using-old-version-of-source-code)

But when I try to run the program after deleting all class files the program doesn't run. Secondly when I compile the program the last modified time of main.class is updated however the last modified time of utitlity.class is not updated. This again is not answered in the aformentioned URL since the java source gets compiled and the class file is created in the expected location.

Comment: Use a real build tool. Maven, Ant, Gradle, and/or sbt.

Comment: For classes referenced from main.java the compiler will use an existing .class file if one exists. Only if none is found it will look for a corresponding .java file.

Comment: Since you are compiling only main.java, the last modified time of that file is updated where as Utility.java is not compiled so its not updated. Compile both classes. As suggested by @ElliottFrisch, use build tool.